# Bifurcations and topological manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I'm following an online course on Differential Geometry by F. Schuller and in this lesson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93f-ayezCqE&t, around 23:00, he draws a bifurcation and says that isn't a topological manifold because any open set around the bifurcation can't be mapped continuously and with continuous inverse to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, etc.

[image: A screenshot of the board, including a tripod that is not homeomorphic to any R^n]

I don't understand why. If we take $\mathbb{R}^2$, I can take every point of the bifurcation and map it to a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (so, a section of $\mathbb{R}^2$) that looks like a Y. Similarly, I can take any point of that curve and map it back to the manifold. What is the problem here? I get why it isn't a *differentiable* manifold, but why not a *topological* manifold?

EDIT: Solved. The problem was that I missed that, by definition, in each point the neighborhood must be mapped not only to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this subset must be open as well, so it can't be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You must have a local homeomorphism to an open ball in $\Bbb R^2$, not to a strange subset. By your logic, every subset of Euclidean space would be a manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin yet it looks like the points that are away from the bifurcation are homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (a line is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$), so if we didn't have the bifurcation it could be a 2D manifold by the definition he gives (a topological space is a 2D manifold if for every point p of the manifold M there exists an open set U(p) for which we can find a map $x(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$). If a line is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, why can't any "strange curve" be?

Comment: You need to understand what open sets are. Is a line locally homeomorphic to an open ball in the plane?

Comment: @TedShifrin I missed that that subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ must also be open, he didn't say that. Now it makes sense indeed.

Comment: Of course he said $U$ and $x(U)$ have to be open.

Comment: I did check. He said open, but did not write it.

Comment: @TedShifrin you’re right, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, any neighborhood of the triple point looks like a $Y$. If this is supposed to have a dimension, it should be $1$-dimensional, since everything away from the triple point looks like an arc. But the triple point itself is not homeomorphic to any connected open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, if we remove the triple point from our neighborhood, we are left with three connected components (the legs of the $Y$), but for any open interval $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if we remove a point we're left with two components! So there can be no homeomorphism from any neighborhood of the triple point to any subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and so the figure is not a manifold.

There are ways to make precise the intuitive idea that if this *were* a manifold, it would have to be $1$-dimensional (for instance, using [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)) which I'll leave unsaid here for simplicity.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: So just for clarification, even the regions away from the bifurcation can't be homeomorphic to R2 but just R?

Comment: That's right, basically because a neighborhood of a point away from the bifurcation looks like an open interval, and one can show (again, this is [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)) that open intervals and open balls aren't homeomorphic (more generally, open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ cannot be homeomorphic for $n \neq m$).